# Mobile Web App using device bluetooth, is it possible and how?

Tags: android, web-applications, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a research project for my company. My goal is to make a mobile web app that uses mobile bluetooth to send data to others mobiles that use the same web app.

I did some research and I found that Chrome for iOS and Android supports an API to use device Buetooth with LE profil: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web?hl=en

If I understood well, it's absolutely not suitable to transfer heavy data. The final goal of my project is to implement something like Hadoop for mobiles phones across a web app: Mobiles will share replicated databases and will perform MapReduce operations on datas.

I'm beginner in development and I don't really know how to find solutions. I think the only solution is to make a native or cordova app.

Do you have some advices on how to perform research on such things when, I guess,  nobody did it yet ? Do you have any ideas to achieve this goal ?